# Qt Disable Windows 10 Game Bar

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I have an application developed in Qt that causes Windows 10 to think it is a game, and opens a pop up box that says `Press the Win-key + G to open the Game bar.` This is very unhelpful as my application is not a game; and it interferes with the user experience. How can I turn this off from within my application code? I have been unable to find any documentation related to this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you target UWP? And can you provide minimal reproducible example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to neither capture Windows shortcuts (in order to stop propagation and disable them), nor to disable game bar in a per-app base.

Options you have are:

1. to disable it globally (see [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1096724/how-to-disable-windows-gamebar-mapping)): you can do it using the Registry, so it can be included in an installation package, but you'll affect the global settings of the user,
2. change the shortcut used to access it in the [Xbox app](https://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-on-windows/social/adjust-game-dvr-settings-windows-10),
3. use some third-party app, such as [AutoHotKey](https://www.autohotkey.com/), to map keyboard sequences to an empty action ([related question](https://superuser.com/questions/987834/how-to-modify-windows-10-keyboard-shortcuts)).

**Edit:**

Also you can (from user side) disable it for your app in Xbox app. ([Xbox support](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/games/game-setup/manage-my-games-list)):

1. Open Xbox app
2. In my games list select your app
3. Right click on it and delete it

This will delete your app from games list, so GameBar will not appear.

Comment: Seeing as it appears to be impossible to disable this easily; I'll mark this as accepted. Thanks for the help!